# Dependency of packages specified in Node js

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

Where is the Node.js package, which is referenced in the `package.json` file, downloaded from when you push an application to Bluemix? When the Node.js application runs in a local environment, it downloads npm js org. However, where does it download from for bluemix?

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix downloads NPM packages the same way it happens in a local environment.

Note: The Bluemix/Node buildpack does cache binaries. If the binary package is the same as the one on the Internet, Bluemix uses the local file in the cache.

Refer to [this blog](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2016/02/04/node-js-buildpack-v30-updates/) to learn how to disable cache.

Comment: You can change the download location using a .npmrc file pushed with the application or by setting the NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY environment variable. Without any configuration, however, the buildpack is just running `npm install` so it would be the same as local.